# how to do this summation in SAS

Tags: sas, addition

```
id      qty  totalqty
0001    1    1
0002    2    2
0002    5    7
0003    7    7
0006    3    3
0006    4    7
```

id already sort in sequence.
I want to sum the qty if the id is the same like what is shown above. So there would be a new variable called totalqty. 
Following is my SAS code. Somehow some rows are right and others are wrong

```
data new; set new;
    totalqty=qty;
        if id = lag1(id) then do;
            totalqty = lag1(totalqty)+qty;
        end;
run;
```

Could someone help me with that? Many thanks!

Comment: Never use a LAG function within a conditional statement. Always do your LAG1 function, but only use it if the condition is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
DATA WANT;
    SET HAVE;
    BY ID;
    IF FIRST.ID AND LAST.ID THEN TOTALQTY = QTY;
    ELSE IF FIRST.ID THEN TOTALQTY = QTY;
    ELSE TOTALQTY+QTY;
RUN;
```

Comment: Thanks again. BTW could you tell me where is the error for my previous code as shown above?

Comment: something that isn't obvious about this solution is that TOTALQTY+QTY causes TOTALQTY to be retained...if it were stated as TOTALQTY=TOTALQTY+QTY, an explicit RETAIN TOTALQTY statement would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more simply as the first two conditions are the same.

DATA WANT;
        SET HAVE;
        BY ID;
        IF FIRST.ID THEN TOTALQTY = QTY;
        ELSE TOTALQTY+QTY;
    RUN;